# Time-stamp takes 1970 | PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following function to convert time to string.

```
function datetime_to_text($datetime = ""){
  $d_t = strtotime($datetime);
  return strftime("%B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p", $d_t);
}
```

MYSQL field type is `timestamp`.

I use the above function as `datetime_to_text($article['article_time']);`

The output is `January 01, 1970 at 01:00 AM`

Comment: it happens if `$article['article_time']` value is not proper. What is its value ?

Comment: 1970-01-01 is the `Unix epoch`  this means that your input is null -->see this:http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: `$article['article_time']` is probably either NULL or an empty string.
`php5 -r 'echo strftime("%B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p",strtotime(null));'` gives:
January 01, 1970 at 01:00 AM%

Comment: What is the problem? what do you want to achieve VS what do you get?

Comment: Exactly what kind of out put you want from this function?

Comment: Please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strtotimes return is

Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE otherwise. Previous to PHP 5.1.0, this function would return -1 on failure.

It seems like the function is failing and returning false. When passed to a function expecting an int. False is cast to 0.

The timestamp 0 is the Unix epoch which is the 1st of Jan 1970.

Check for failure of the strtotime function and handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing $datetime variables value is not in date format.
Please try below code

```
function datetime_to_text($datetime){

  $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

  $d_t = strtotime($datetime);  
  $d_t = trim($d_t); 

  echo strftime("%B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p", $d_t);

}

$ex_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

datetime_to_text($ex_date);
```